# ActiveXObject issue in javaScript

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer, activex

I wrote a javascript function in my html page to execute an .exe file. for this i used ActiveXObject.
my function is:

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~JavaScript~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
function openWin(url)
 {

  if (!document.all) {
         alert ("Available only with Internet Explorer.");
     return;
   }


var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
ws.Exec(url);
}
```

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

It works fine but there is a alert "**An ActiveX control might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page. Do you want to allow this interaction?**" comes up to confirm. If i say YES only it will get loaded.

Pls anyone help me on this how to avoid this pop-up coming every time when i reload my html page.

Comment: Why do you want to `Exec` a url?  Why not use `window.open`?  The only use I can think of for using `Exec` on a url is to open it in the user's default browser, which seems like an odd thing to do from a web page.

Comment: hi Andy : window.open will create new Tab. Am not loading my exe into browser. exe will load independently.

Answer (score 3):

**You** can't. Your users can, by giving your page trusted access to their computer (e.g., by adding the URL to the "Trusted Sites" zone).

Comment: +1.  The only reason I can think you would want to `Exec` a url is to have it open in the default browser which might not necessarily be the one in use.

Comment: Am trying to load a flash exe file from my html page. Exe is located in a remote path.

Comment: exe will load separately not inside the browser or any new window. it will load independently.

Comment: @shan: executing a url is the same as typing a url in your default browser.  The same effect would be given by just providing a direct link to the file.  Even a flash exe would not execute automatically, the user would be presented with a file download box instead.  Your only options are to either embed the flash movie into a web page or ask your users to download and open the file.

Comment: i tested this in my local machine by giving the path of an exe file which is in my local system. same pop-up appearing.

Comment: @shan: You'll need to adjust the security settings for the zone your browser thinks your page is in (hopefully Trusted Sites or Intranet) to allow ActiveX without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable activeX in Internet explorer security settings.

http://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/adams/install/enabling-active-x.html

If you want your users to not seeing this message, then they should enable it. But you can't force them to do it because of security issues.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But already my IE browser setting are the same. :-(